# SSIS Merge Join on Column with Host and IP mixed

Tags: sql-server, join, merge, ssis, etl

Need some help on figuring out why the Merge Join operation is having problems joining on IP address in my column.

I have 2 CSV files with below information in them, the joining column is the ClientName and the overall goal is to get

```
Array|ClientName|ResolvedClientName|Path
```

from my Merge Join.

*CSV1*

```
   Array    |   ClientName   |          Path
 ___________|________________|______________________
  myArray1  |     server1    |  /something/something
  myArray1  |     server2    |  /something/something
  myArray1  |  192.168.0.55  |  /something/something
  myArray2  |  192.172.6.10  |  /something/something
  myArray2  |     server5    |  /something/something
```

*CSV2*

```
      ClientName  |   ResolvedClientName
   _______________|______________________
       server1    |        server1
       server2    |        server2
    192.168.0.55  |        server3
    192.172.6.10  |        server4
       server5    |        server5
```

Pulling these both in and performing the Merge Join on them is simple enough, the output on the connection are both strings and the operation works great on the ones with just text (server1/2/5).  However where it falls apart is on the IP addresses, and it seems to be due to the '.' in them.  After testing out on a random set of numbers (12345) in both and seeing that it did join this was the only conclusion I could come to.

Anyone have any experience with this, maybe a workaround?

Comment: If they are strings they should all work in the same way. Have you checked for trailing spaces, etc.?

Comment: @Matt the OP posted some sample data as a comment to my answer. It looks like there is some unicode characters in the value, and there are not visible to the editor that he is using. Take a look at my answer update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Suggested Solution

*Just follow these steps:*

1. First add 2 Flat File Sources (2 CSV)
2. After Each connector add a Derived Column Transformation for `ClientName` using the following expression *(To remove trailing spaces and update to uppercase)*

   ```
   UPPER(TRIM([ClientName])
   ```
3. After Derived Columns add a Sort component and Select Column `[ClientName]` to sort by *(on each file)*
4. Use the merge join component

If this didn't work the issue may be caused by a difference in encoding, or there is some unicode characters that are invisible to your editor that causes this issue

## UPDATE 1

*Based on the OP comment: `if you were to try these 2 cases in a CSV file I believe you'd see the same results I am, first one works, second one doesn't...`*

```
ArrayName|ClientName|MountPath 
array2.nam.nsroot.net|144.215.120.114|/mwdctov0285/ctoqt0285‌​
array1-pr‌​.nam.nsroot.net|10.1‌​02.133.24|/mwdcerv06‌​18/cerqt0618

ClientName|ResolvedClientName 
144.215.120.114|client3.nam.nsroot.net
10.102.133.‌​24|client1.nam.nsroo‌​t.net`
```

**Solution:**

After getting this sample data, i copied them directly from your comments to my *Notepad++* editor and i found that there are some unicode characters which appear as a question marks, which will cause difference between values

[image]

One Suggestion is to add a Script component after each source and use a script to get a new output column *(Derived Column can be removed)*

*Example:*

```
If Not Row.ClientName_IsNull AndAlso _
   Not String.IsnullOrEmpty(Row.ClientName) Then

   Row.OutClientName = Regex.Replace(Row.ClientName, "[^0-9.]", "").ToUpper

   Else

   Row.OutClientName_IsNull = True
End If
```

*Note: You have to Imports `System.Text.RegularExpressions` to use `RegEx`*

Comment: Well, that kind of worked, it was able to make the join on 135 new cases with IP Addresses but still misses a lot of others.

Comment: @Wingman1487 final thing to try is to change both column to uppercase. check my update *(derived column expression)*

Comment: Made the change, still the same result.  Its just bizarre to me, looking at the CSV files there is no difference in the IP column, no odd characters, just straight IP's and Host names.

Comment: @Wingman1487 last try, just cast both column to the same unicode `(DT_WSTR,50)UPPER(TRIM([ClientName])` to check that it is note an encoding issue

Comment: @Wingman1487 with the information you supplied i don't think you will get another suggestion. if you can attach sample files it will be better

Comment: Same result, Derived Column settings like below
Derived Column Name: ClientName
Derived Column: Replace 'ClientName'
Expression: (DT_WSTR,50)UPPER(TRIM(ClientName))
Data Type: string[DT_STR]
Length: 150
Precision:
Scale:
Code Page: 1252 (ANSI - Latin I)

Comment: @Wingman1487 if you cannot provide sample data, there is other things to try. Hope that i helped you even a little bit. good luck

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get a sample out to you, however if you were to try these 2 cases in a CSV file I believe you'd see the same results I am, first one works, second one doesn't, sorry for how ugly this is. `ArrayName|ClientName|MountPath
array2.nam.nsroot.net|144.215.120.114|/mwdctov0285/ctoqt0285<linebreak>array1-pr.nam.nsroot.net|10.102.133.24|/mwdcerv0618/cerqt0618` and this `ClientName|ResolvedClientName
144.215.120.114|client3.nam.nsroot.net<linebreak>10.102.133.24|client1.nam.nsroot.net`

Comment: Thanks for the help!  This worked and also put me on to some alternative ways to look at the outputs.